# Java ProcessBuilder Pipe

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have a shell command `my_command` that accepts a pipe as input , eg

```
echo "test" | my_command param1 param2
```

I tried this:

```
cmd.add("echo");
cmd.add( "test");
cmd.add("| my_command");
cmd.add(param1);
cmd.add(param2);
```

but i did I not get desired result. `cmd` is a list declared using `ArrayList`. thanks

Answer (score 2):

ProcessBuilder can run only programs but echo is not a program but one of cmd's (in Windows) command. You should run `cmd /c echo ...` in Java